# issue in appcelerator createlabel visible false

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have created a label using Titanium.UI.createLabel and set its property visible:false. But it is showing in windows phone.

I have tried with changing its zindex with respect to main layout but didn't work.
Did anyone face same problem in appcelerator in windows phone?
Any help is appreciable. Thank you!

```
var lblStatus=Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text:L("Status_header"),
        textAlign:"left",
        height:"20dp",
        left:"8dp",
        top:"361dp",
        width:"305dp",
        visible:false,
        zindex:0
    });
```

Comment: Did you have any other elements with different zindex?

Comment: No, I don't have other element with zindex. I have tried this to make it invisible using other element zindex higher but no use. Tx

Comment: I think your code is correct, can you post all controller?
Did you try to run the same code on android for example? Just for exclude incompatibility with windows phone

Comment: which version of windows phone are you using?

Comment: @Alka it looks like you've hit a parity bug if this is hiding on other platforms but not on Windows Phone. You should report this bug at [Appcelerator's JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org) if you can't find a ticket for it already.

Answer (score 1):

Try these two things:

1. `visible: "false"`
2. `height: 0`